# Writing strings to files

Tags: python, string, file

Using this:

```
def Files(x,y,z):
  newH = x[:2]
  newH+Hero == open(x , "w")
  newH+Hero.write('z','y')
  newH+Hero.close()
```

I am trying to create a new file for each of the options 24 total yet the error is: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'
exited with non-zero status any ideas?

Comment: 1. You cannot have a `+` in variable names. 2. `newH+Hero == open(x , "w")` is a comparison, not an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

As it has already been mentioned `+` cannot be in variable names in python.

If I understood you correctly you need a function `Files` (which again is not a recommended way to name functions in python, it should start with lowercase letter) which accepts 3 parameters: `x` - file name to write to, `y` and `z` are the strings to be written to file `x`.

Again, it's better to use more meaningful names for your variables and parameters like `filename`, name0, name1 (if your other parameters are some string names).

Your function can be something like this:

```
def files(x, y, z):
    with open(x, 'w') as f:
        f.write(y)
        f.write(z)
```

This function will open a file with name `x` and write `y` and `z` (I suspect that they are strings in your case) to the file `x`.

Comment: I've got a suspicion that `Hero` is a global (or member) variable set to one of the 24 options mentioned, so `with open(x+Hero, 'w') as f:` might possibly be closer to what the OP wants. However, we still need more clarification.